# Sails.js and MongoDB saving user in "admin" database instead of "myDatabase"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I have this config in sails.js `config/connection.js`:

```
mongo: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'myPassword',
    database: 'myDatabase',
    schema: true
  },
```

When i run `sails lift` i get these errors:

```
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running?
 Error details:
{ [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }
    at _createError (/home/myuser/nodejs-tests/activityOverlord/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:98:23)
    at /home/myuser/nodejs-tests/activityOverlord/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:101:13
    at /home/myuser/nodejs-tests/activityOverlord/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/connection.js:25:20
    at /home/myuser/nodejs-tests/activityOverlord/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:457:15
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

I have a register form that saves the user in MongoDB but instead of saving the data into "myDatabase" it's saving it into "admin" database i want to use my own database (it is already created)

this is the admin user saved into "admin" db:

```
{
    "_id": "admin.admin",
    "user": "admin",
    "db": "admin",
    "credentials": {
        "MONGODB-CR": "b92c43a8b2da7f6275322fc4b2177424"
    },
    "roles": [
        {
            "role": "root",
            "db": "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

hope anyone can help me with this, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i could do it... i needed a `dbOwner` user

```
 "roles": [
        {
            "role": "dbOwner",
            "db": "myDatabase"
        }
```

and i use mongo-express so i needed another user admin as `root` to control everything from the UI

```
{
    "_id": "admin.admin",
    "user": "admin",
    "db": "admin",
    "credentials": {
        "MONGODB-CR": "b92c43a8b2da7f6275322fc4b2177424"
    },
    "roles": [
        {
            "role": "root",
            "db": "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

good luck if anyone need to do this